# SharePoint SPFX : Workbench issues

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

[image]

The above shown is the configuration of serve.json and when i gulp serve its redirecting to this url https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench.html and the page shows empty.

Here is the image below

[image]

Comment: Have you reviewed the browser console output as if you are using react or similar you may have a render error?

Comment: Can you let us know the browser in which you browsing ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `.vscode\launch.json` file inside your solution folder for and you may have a debug configuration set to launch that url, and if so update it to use the url in the `serve.json`

Comment: same response no use sir

Answer (score 0):

The workbench doesn't load at all on IE11, yet it works correctly on Chrome.And if you check in IE developer tool console,there can be two errors in the console:

- SCRIPT1053: Const must be initialized
  workbenchInit.js (10,21)
- SCRIPT5007: Object expected
  sp-loader-assembly_default.js (5854,13)

[You can also check with the node and spfx version according to the Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment)